# su issues for non-root user if SELinux is on

Tags: pam, selinux

I have a common user on my RHEL 7.6 server and when SELinux is off, su command works for it. But when SElinux is on, su command doesn't work anymore.
In the PAM sources I found that

```
#ifndef HELPER_COMPILE
if (geteuid() || SELINUX_ENABLED)
    return PAM_UNIX_RUN_HELPER;
#endif
```

a special command `unix_chkpwd` is used to check the password if SELinux is on. This command has a code:

```
user = getuidname(getuid());
/* if the caller specifies the username, verify that user
  matches it */
if (strcmp(user, argv[1])) {
 user = argv[1];
 /* no match -> permanently change to the real user and proceed */
 if (setuid(getuid()) != 0)
   return PAM_AUTH_ERR;
```

In my case user is common user name and argv[1] is root, and in that case setuid is executed for uid of common user.
Do you know why it works so?
Is any way to make su works when SELinux is on?

Answer (score 1):

from my RHEL 7.9 system:

```
semanage login -l | more

Login Name           SELinux User         MLS/MCS Range        Service

__default__          unconfined_u         s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
root                 unconfined_u         s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
system_u             system_u             s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
```

that is the default setup from RHEL, and if it is modified then I have experienced `su` not working when selinux is enforcing, even though a user is in the `wheel` group.  I believe it comes down to knowing how to use selinux to add those wheel group users that should be allowed to su the proper selinux label or context.

And it may be this, in `visudo`:

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) TYPE=sysadm_t ROLE=sysadm_r ALL
```

This is from the v3r4 stig, which is when I experienced *su issues for non-root user if SELinux is on* after trying to apply that semanage security instruction.  Do a `setenforce 0` and `su` would work as expected.  If you don't know what STIG means or never did an `semange` command then this is probably not your cause.

I take it for granted now, in RHEL 7, that if any non-root user wishes to `su` then they need to be in the `wheel` group.  What `/etc/?` file that is set in where you can undo that and allow any user to `su` I do not know.  But the traditional simple aspect of only wheel group users can su is generally independent of selinux by default.

Answer (score 0):

Due to doc https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-targeted_policy-confined_and_unconfined_users (see Table 3.1) staff users can't execute `su`, only `sudo`